# How to Write a JQuery for on one div mouseover update another div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

Here My scenario as follows..
 i have list of div s contains patientid and another information on mouse over we are plan to show the total patient information in another div.how can i achieve this in ruby on rails please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery mouseover event to send ajax request to rails like

```
$(".some-div").mouseover(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: {patientid: some_id},
        url: "/your_controllers/your_action"
    );
}
```

then in your controller

```
class YourControllersController < ApplicationController

  def your_action
    @model = Model.find(params[:patientid])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

then create views/your_controllers/your_action.js.erb contain code like this

```
$(".expected-to-update-div").html(<%= @model.id %>);
```